# MVC Convert Multiple Stream to Single PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

How can I convert multiple Crystal Report export Stream into single PDF file.
Please Help

Comment: You're going to need to provide more information than that if you don't want the question to be closed quickly. Are the streams you already have in PDF format? Is your question simply "How to merge multiple PDF files?" or do you need to convert the crystal report to PDF? Both of which already have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

The Crystal runtime alone cannot merge pdf files. You need to use a pdf component and take care of the merge step yourself.

Alternatively, there are 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation tools that indeed take care of both exporting the report as well as merging multiple outputs.